# Python client keeps loosing connection to tcp socket connection

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, websocket

I am writing a python server client using TCP connecton SOCK_STREAM.

I am able to make one connection from the client and the server returns the response.

The second time the connection is lost from what I am seeing

Here is the server code

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverPort = 62175
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('The server is ready to receive information')
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
while True:
       sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
       capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
       connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence.encode()) 
       connectionSocket.close()
```

Here is the code for the client

```
from socket import *
import sys
import re

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 62175
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))
regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
done = False
while done == False:
    sentence = input("Input a lowercase sentence: ")
    try:
        inputValue = int(sentence)
        print("Input data is an integer, suppose to be a string, Run the program again")
    except ValueError:     
        try:
            if(regex.search(sentence) == None):   
                if (sentence.lower() == "quit"):
                    done = True
                    clientSocket.close()
                elif (sentence == ""):
                    print("There wasn't any input detected. Try again")
                else:
                    clientSocket.sendall(sentence.encode())
                    modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
                    print(modifiedSentence.decode())
                    print(done)
            else:
                print("String contains special characters, Try again")
        except OSError as err:
            print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
```

Here is the output and error when I enter a second input

```
Input a lowercase sentence: test
TEST
False
Input a lowercase sentence: test
OS error: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Thank you for the assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server closes the connection inside the loop but tries to communicate through the closed socket:

```
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
while True:
       sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
       ...
       connectionSocket.close()
```

To handle multiple `recv` and `send` within the connection you should call `close` only when you are actually done:

```
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
while True:
       sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
       ...
connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: Tried adding into the loop but get OS error: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine...

Comment: @JoseOrtiz: I see that the intend of your server was slightly different than I though first and that the error was on a different place. Fixed the answer.

Comment: That worked... python indentations do not make sense to me..... so with the indent back to the left makes it that connectionSocket.close is not part the the code  from sentence to the encode()) ?

Comment: @JoseOrtiz: *"python indentations do not make sense to me"* - Proper indentations in Python are one of the most essentials parts of the language. I think you need to understand how these work before doing any more Python. In a nutshell: Indentation describe which block it belongs to.